# Returns null during reading data from firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I am fetching data of a collection from firebase and it returns null. It works if I change the collection name but then again it shows the above problem.

Comment: Please add the actual code/error to your question instead of a picture.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

**You are doing the wrong code formate**

***Please follow below code formate for right response***

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Container(child:Text("error"),);
          }  
   else if(snapshot.hasData){
                 
 return 
                   .....
                     your widget listview
                     .....


            }  else{
            return Center(child: circularProgress(),);

            }
```