# Dsiplaying information only for the logged in user

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to ask for a suggestion on what might be wrong with my code.
I am trying to display data from firebase only for the logged-in user.

Here is a sample of my code

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.27;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Upcoming appointments"),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collectionGroup('client_bookings')
                      .where("email",
                          isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
                            var data = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                            return Text(data["email"]);
                    
                          });
                    } else {
                      return Text("error message");
                    }
                  })
            ]))));
  }
```

When i run the app it shows the error message.The output on the console is
'''
W/ProviderInstaller(25111): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
'''
Do you have an idea where might be my mistake? I have an email column storing the user who booked the appt inside that collection group.

If i remove the where condition my code works fine.

[image: email field in the db]

Comment: Make sure , you have internet connection into your device

Comment: Yes, I have an internet connection, code works fine when i remove the where condition. However, I am aiming to show only the data for the logged in user.

Comment: Please print the log of snapshot.hasData

Comment: Also the print FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email --> email is matching with your db? please match and let me know

Comment: the output is true. I/flutter (25112): true

Comment: Replace your listview item count with this snapshot.data?.docs.length

Comment: See the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75335357/returns-null-during-reading-data-from-firebase/75335953#75335953

Comment: I followed the code from the answer. Still no result. It gives an error again. When I run the code i can see the correct output for 1 second, and the screen is blinking then an error message is displayed.

Comment: i added a screenshot of the email field in my db, it is matching

Comment: now i am getting this in the console  Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

Comment: Wrap your listview with sizebox and give some height width